# C - properly partitioning the code into multiple files

Tags: c, module, include, header-files, redefinition

I'm writing a program in C and I'm separating the parts in different .c files (modules).

Some modules (say B and C) include the same module (say A) and when these modules (B and C) are included by another module (say D), a diamond "hierarchy" is formed that causes redefinition problems.

Eg.

**vec3.c**

```
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
} vec3;

float dot(vec3 v1, vec3 v2) {
    return v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y + v1.z*v2.z;
}

/* ... other stuff ... */
```

**ray.c**

```
#include "vec3.c"

typedef struct {
    vec3 A, B;
} ray;

vec3 origin(ray r) {
    return r.A;
}

/* ... other stuff ... */
```

**sphere.c**

```
#include "ray.c"

typedef struct {
    float t;
    vec3 p;
    vec3 n;
} record;

typedef struct {
    vec3 center;
    float radius;
} sphere;

typedef enum {false, true} bool;

bool hit_sphere(sphere s, ray r, float tmin, float tmax, record *rec) {
    /* ... do stuff ... */
}

/* ... other stuff ... */
```

**camera.c**

```
#include "ray.c"

typedef struct {
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 lower_left_corner;
    vec3 horizontal;
    vec3 vertical;
} camera;

/* ... other stuff ... */

vec3 origin = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
vec3 lower_left_corner = {-2.0, -1.0, -1.0};
vec3 horizontal = {4.0, 0.0, 0.0};
vec3 vertical = {0.0, 2.0, 0.0};

camera cam = {origin, lower_left_corner, horizontal, vertical};
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "sphere.c"
#include "camera.c"

/* ... other stuff ... */

int main() {
    /* ... do stuff ... */
}
```

In this case the problem arises because both camera.c and sphere.c include ray.c (and hence also vec3.c), so there is a double definition of the structures and functions defined in these modules.

How can I rearrange the code to not have these problems?

Thanks!

Comment: You should **never** `#include` source files. Write header files (`.h`) containing **only** declarations and *include-guard macros*.

Comment: There's no one single rule to split a project into multiple files. *Except* that structures and declarations (like function prototypes) should be in *header files* and you should never `#include` source files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no language-defined rule about file organization. Actually, all files included into your source file form so-called "compilation unit" created by precompiler, and are treated by compiler as single file. Precompiler's directive `#include` literally does that... includes that other file into the current file being processed. Thus it is essential to  ensure that files are included only once.

A classic way to do so is to use #ifndef directive of preprocessor. Most compilers support directive `#pragma once` but it is not a standart tool, that sometimes behaves unpredictably in case of circular includes.

It is accepted practice to call files that contain reusable declarations and definitions "headers" and give them .h (and .hpp sometimes). C++ standard headers agreed to not have extension at all to avoid mixing them with C headers. E.g. stdio.h  is superceded by cstdio and former shouldn't be used  in C++. Sometimes there is requrement to include large repetetive definitions, that can get different extensions  .inc, .incl , etc.

So why people do say "never include .c files". It's related to the toolchain used, the set of utilities that control application's building process. You would almost never run compiler manually. There always is a building tool that usually decides what to do with file , basing that decision on extension. .c files usually considered to represent separate compilation modules, so tool would run compiler for EACH of them, before trying to link them together.

Headers should not define objects such as functions or variables, they can declare them for external linking. Why? If you include header file with defined variable into several compilation units, you'll get an error from linker, because all units will contain same symbol. So, definition should be unique or program is considered ill-formed. Functions always assumed to have external linking by default

```
/* myheader.h */
#ifndef ___MYHEADER_H
#define ___MYHEADER_H

extern int globalVariable;

typedef struct MyType {

};

int foo(MyType);

#endif

/* myheader.cpp */
#include "myheader.h"

int globalVariable = 5;

int foo(MyType param)
{
/* body of foo */
}
```

How files are organized in project is up to designer. If you're part of team, you're expected to follow recommendations of that team's lead designer or their approved documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You should never include `.c` files.

Create for each implementation file (`.c`), a header file (`.h`) and declare therein the functions. Then include the header file instead in your corresponding implementation file. Once declared and included you should write the implementation of those declared functions in your implementation file.

Then to use the functions you include the header file.

Example of a header file (example.h):

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

/* Function declarations */
void example();

#endif /* EXAMPLE_H */
```

Example of an implementation file (example.c):

```
#include "example.h"

void example() {
    /* TODO: add logic */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! That's what I tried to do, but the problem remains on the structures and typedef: they must be placed in the .c file or in the .h? For example, for the vec3.c module, where does the definition of the vec3 structure be placed? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ArcticPi For functions that has to be accessible by other .c files they should be declared in the .h file. Then #include the .h file in the .c file which is going to use your function.

Comment: @Arctic Pi those are declaration, if they are meant to be reusable, place them into header. While typedef means type definition, the syntctic unit that starts with the keyword is called typedef declaration. See my answer